# photo credit and the opening credit

Tags: nouns

The item 7 in http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/credit.

> recognition by name of a person contributing to a performance (as a film or telecast) `<the opening credits>`

Is the same meaning for the credit in `photo credit`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To **credit** somebody means to publicly acknowledge them as a participant in something.

In the case of a *photo credit*, the protographer is being publicly acknowledged as the source of the photograph.

In the case of *opening credits*, participants in the production of that show or movie (actors, writers etc) are being publicly acknowledged for the role they each played in that production.

So yes, the usage of the word 'credit' in both cases is the same.